# How to do Cross-Correlation

Tags: java, audio, signal-processing, fft, cross-correlation

I need cross-correlation to compare two sound files(speech) and find similarities.
What I have done so far is created a voice recorder that removes parts where I do not say anything, and also I have implemented fft, so I know the magnitude and the peak frequency.
I managed to create my own Cross-Correlation matrix by using the formula(and the knowledge of using it from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQm6ZP1F6ms&t=767s) youtube video. My implementation:
`

```
    private int intersection(File file1, File file2) {
        int intersections = 0;
        try {
            Complex[] Sfft = getFFT(file1);
            Complex[] Tfft = getFFT(file2);
            for (int i = 0; i < Tfft.length; i++) {
                Tfft[i] = Tfft[i].conjugate();
            }
            Complex[] correlation = new Complex[Sfft.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < correlation.length; i++) {
                correlation[i] = Sfft[i].times(Tfft[i]);
            }
            FFT.ifft(correlation);
            intersections = CrossCorrelation.argmax(correlation);
            System.out.println(correlation.length);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return intersections;
    }
```

I used fft from [here](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/FFT.java.html)
and the corresponding Complex class [Complex](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/97data/Complex.java.html)
and My argmax method :

```
    public static int argmax(Complex[] a)
        {
            double y = Double.MIN_VALUE;
            int idx = -1;

            for(int x = 0; x < a.length; x++)
            {
                if(a[x].abs() > y)
                {
                    y = a[x].abs();
                    idx = x;
                }
            }

            return idx;
        }
```

But when I run My cross-correlation program, it is not even close to being true.

Comment: You need to zero pad the two inputs to size M+N-1 (where M and N are the lengths of the two inputs in samples). The resulting cross correlation vector will also be of size M+N-1.

Comment: If your FFT only works with power of 2 sizes then zero pad to at least M+N-1 and round up to next power of 2 if needed.

Comment: I do not understand, can You please provide an example?

Comment: Suppose you want to use the FFT method to cross correlate two vectors A = [ 1, 2, 3 ] (size M = 3) and B = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] (size N = 5) then they need to be zero padded to size M+N-1 = 7, so A = [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0  ] and B = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0 ].

Comment: And if your FTT library only works with sizes which are a power of 2 then you would need to pad them to the next power of 2, which would be 8 in the above example, so A = [ 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] and B = [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 0, 0 ].